# Best way to avoid print head clogging when not using printer?

Tags: printing, printer

I'm new to the printing game and recently acquired a Canon Pro-10. During my comparison research, there was a lot of discussion around not letting the printer sit for any length of time, as pigments tend to clog up the print head.

Now, the printer has been great, but I'm about to go on a two week vacation. I'd love to not have to deal with clogged print heads when I return.

So, the question is, is two weeks enough time to warrant clogging concerns and if so, how can I prevent clogging?

[This question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80168/how-can-i-keep-an-inkjet-printer-in-good-shape-when-i-wont-be-around-for-half-a) details how to get a printer ready for long-term disuse, but this isn't really my case. I'm more interested in intermittent, shorter periods of disuse over long term storage.

Some tech specifics as asked by comment:

- Printer: Canon Pro-10
- Computer: Dell XPS 13 running Win 10
- My own tech capability: I do front-end dev, so setting something up requiring a bit of coding isn't completely foreign, though the exact process will be.

Comment: What sort of computer is it connected to (mainly the operating system; this would be trvial on Linux using `cron` to send a test page)?  Is the computer going to be left on? That would seem wasteful in terms of power.

Comment: @ChrisH - I added some details to the post. All devices can be left on.

Comment: This is more of a hardware printer question rather than a printing workflow question. Maybe off topic? If needs be maybe try Superuser? (could explain the -1)

Comment: I'm rusty on windows, but autohotkey would provide a solution (essentially click the "test page" button in the printer properties dialogue box every few days). Reluctantly I think @CrazyDino is right -- a good question but in slightly the wrong place.

Comment: I don't know how so I can't write an answer, Windows has a task scheduler I believe.. so you could attach this to a batch file? Again probs wrong place.

Comment: @CrazyDino - I figured it was prob the wrong place when I wrote the question - but figured there is a higher probability of another photographer running into this issue and solving it pragmatically here over a software developer throwing out a potentially theoretical solution. But yea, I'll probably post this question there as well.

Comment: Guys, I'm pretty sure that "downvote" is not the proper reaction to a question that needs to be migrated.  It's at least tangentially related to photography, and the question is a well formed, valid question.  Flag the question to bring it to a mods attention.

Comment: @JPhi1618, there's always going to be that sourpuss that downvotes something because they just don't like it, and without offering any comment. But, if it makes them feel just a little better about life, I guess I'm happy to have helped them.

Comment: I actually had this same question, so I would like to see an answer on _any_ of the SE sites...

Comment: @JPhi1618, I updated the title to be less specific to 'print every x days' - hopefully the question gets a bit more love.

Comment: The question has absolutely nothing to do with photography. I don't yet have the rep on this particular SE to do anything more than vtc as 'off topic' but someone with better rep, or the OP, could flag to migrate to super user, or maybe graphics [I'd go with super user as it's essentially a 'computer equipment' question] (not an answer, but switching the printer off completely for 2 weeks would be far better for the heads than leaving it on)

Comment: @Tetsujin, I was unaware of Superuser.SE before this but will flag the post for migration. Could you extrapolate on your comment that power down would be better than sending an autoprint? I don't understand how that would make a difference to the ink-clog.

Comment: @CrazyDino - personally, this seems on topic to me.  It's photographic equipment and maintenance of it seems on topic.  A question about how to clean a lens would be on topic.  Why would maintenance of a photo printer not similarly be on topic?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used ink-jets, so the tech may have moved on since [I switched to lasers for 'officey' stuff 10 years ago & outsource my 'art' printing] but it was always the case that the heads would dry out if the machine was left on - even though it sleeps - compared to simply switching it off completely. There were anecdotal tales of also wrapping the head structure in cling-film [saran-wrap] for extended periods... but I never actually tried that, sounds a bit too Heath-Robinson for my liking.

Comment: I'm with @AJHenderson on this. Specifically, when using a printer (either inkjet or laser) just for general documents and stuff, this was never a worry — the precision just doesn't matter. When I was doing my own inkjet photo prints, though, I did that about once every month, and every time there was a hassle. So, I think there _is_ a photography angle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I keep an inkjet printer in good shape when I won't be around for half a year?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80168/how-can-i-keep-an-inkjet-printer-in-good-shape-when-i-wont-be-around-for-half-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know specifically for the Pro-10, but I know that if I leave my Pro-1 on, it automatically moves the ink a bit periodically anyway to avoid clogged heads.  I don't print anything on it sometimes for months at a time without any issue.

Comment: Is the printer powered up and moving the ink during these months or completely powered down?

Comment: @Corey powered on.  If I leave it powered off it has to go through a very ink heavy cleaning.  I've had periods of a few weeks with it off by accident before without issue as well (other than burning a bunch of ink when I turned it back on.)

Comment: I wanted to report back on this. The Canon Pro-10 seems to like to power itself off after so much non-use. I didn't want to risk anything so I had our pet sitter turn the printer on once per day. Result: No clogging. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Back when I used Epson printers I was constantly fighting the clogged head monster if a printer when unused for several days. That was one of several reasons why I moved to outsourcing photographic prints for anything other than casual personal usage.

My last couple of 'home' printers, used for printing documents, receipts, etc. when needed have been Canon Pixma 'MG' series printers. As long as they are left powered up and turned on they will periodically perform a short cleaning cycle that keeps the heads clean. I rarely use it more than 3-5 times a month to print out grocery shopping lists, restaurant coupons, etc. I do occasionally print a full color glossy 4x6 or 5x7 with it. In the 20 months I've had the Pixma MG7520 I've only gone through two full sets of ink cartridges and am currently barely started on the third set. I've never had a clogged head. (The heads in the MG7520 and its predecessor, an MG5320, are permanent heads installed in the printer. The ink cartridges are tanks only, unlike other brands that place the print heads on the business end the ink cartridges.)